# SQL Server Management Objects for Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-phone-8

Can I use SQL Server Management Objects in Windows Phone 8 app to manage SQL Server ?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Management Objects resides in the [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo Namespace](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.aspx), which is not present in the [.NET API for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207211%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).  There might be a way to get it on there, but I doubt it.